# How can i change a jwplayer's element style applied with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, styles, jwplayer, elementstyle

I'm using **Jwplayer** plugin to include an audio note on my website.

The audio container div (#player_wrapper) doesn't have any style added in the HTML, but still, some styles are added to it via javasctipt... therefore, they appear in the element style on the browser's inspector.

Here's the CSS added to #player_wrapper:

```
element.style {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

How can I change **"display: block;"** to **"display: table;"**?

Thanks.